# How to get the PostgreSQL db backup from slave if master down

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

I have setup **PostgreSQL** hot stand by replication on Ubuntu. I need to know if master DB server is down, then how to get the backup from the slave.

I have tried this command

```
pg_dump testdb > /var/lib/postgresql/20190306.bak -p 5433
```

I got this error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "channeldb" failed:
FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific error has nothing to do with this being a standby server.

Rather, you forgot to use the `-U` option to specify the database user, so `pg_dump` assumes it is the same as the operating system user.

Don't use the root user for anything but administrative activities!